# Streaming raspberry pi cam to video room @ Janus gateway on the Internet

Tags: python, gstreamer

We are trying to establish a 1 to 1 audio connection via a web client (chrome web browser) to a PI4 Raspberry device, using Gstreamer in python3.
We have used the code found on
https://github.com/centricular/gstwebrtc-demos/blob/master/janus/janusvideoroom.py

For the connection we have the following pipe:

```
PIPELINE_DESC = ''' webrtcbin name=sendrecv stun-server=stun://stun.l.google.com:19302
 alsasrc device=hw:1 ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! queue !
 opusenc ! rtpopuspay !
 queue ! application/x-rtp,media=audio,encoding-name=OPUS,payload=96 !
 sendrecv.
'''
```

The connection is successful and the user appears in the web client.
On the browser client we can successfully hear the audio stream from the Raspberry source.
On the other side, the audio sent from the web client to raspberry is not audible.
We have tested the audio output on the raspberry board, using MP4 stream and the audio output is working fine.

We cannot grab the audio stream from Janus.
How can we solve it? Any clue?